# Razor view capture RadioButtonFor with enum source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC3 and Razor view, I have the view populating with the proper data

**HelperModel**

```
public partial class Visibility
    {
        public enum VisibilityLevel { ShowThis, HideThis, HideAll }
        ...
    }
public partial class Address
    {
        public Visibility.VisibilityLevel Visibility{
            get {
                ...
```

**View**

```
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HIDE_DATA, Models.Visibility.VisibilityLevel.ShowThis ) <span>Show @Model.TYPE_DESC address</span><br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HIDE_DATA, Models.Visibility.VisibilityLevel.HideThis) <span>Don't show @Model.TYPE_DESC address </span><br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HIDE_DATA, Models.Visibility.VisibilityLevel.HideAll) <span>Don't show ANY addresses</span><br />
```

**Controller**

```
 //
 // POST: /Address/Edit/5

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(Address addr,string submitButton)
 {
     ...
```

This populated the page properly based on the data and model definition however the post back does not get the new value.  When I inspect the controller the Address model that is passed on submit has the original value of the RadioButton, not the value selected or changed by the user.  What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of using the enum values, just cast them to int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to not be an issue with enum, my custom attribute did not have a setter.

Changed

**HelperModel**

```
    Visibility.VisibilityLevel _vizibility;

    public Visibility.VisibilityLevel Visibility{
        get {
            if (_vizibility != Models.Visibility.VisibilityLevel.ShowThis)  //the default
                return _hide_data;
            var ans =  new MacDirectEntities()
            ...
            return ans.Visibility;
        }
        set {
            _vizibility= value;
        }
    }
}
```